# firebase observeSingleEvent never executing

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a function that will return when the database is finished filling data, however the callback is never executing.

```
func dbFillTest(finished: @escaping ()->()) {
    if let clientId = id {
        print("~~~")
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users").child(clientId).child("info").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (userSnap) in
            print("~~~~")
            finished()
        })
    } else { finished() }
}
```

and I call it with:

```
object.dbFillTest {
    // finished() code here. THIS IS NOT EXECUTING
}
```

Why would the database callback not be executing?

Thank you

Comment: Cant really say w/o seeing the JSON DB structure of yours, and what is object?

Comment: object is an object to be filled with the database data